# dart pub dependency pointing to a library on the local machine

Tags: dependencies, dart, dart-pub

E.g. I have created a library, but it only exists only on my local machine.
I want to create a separate app, which uses this library.
How can I do this with pub?

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with `path`:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

From [the documentation](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages):

> This says the root directory for transmogrify is
>   /Users/me/transmogrify. When you use this, pub will generate a symlink
>   directly to the lib directory of the referenced package directory. Any
>   changes you make to the dependent package will be seen immediately.
>   You don’t need to run pub every time you change the dependent package.

Comment: Does it have to point to the library project directory ?
I tried different paths and always get     Pub install fail, No source named path is registered

Comment: It looks like the `path` source is not implemented: http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdart%2Futils%2Fpub -- all I see is `git_source.dart`, `hosted_source.dart`, `root_source.dart` and `sdk_source.dart`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Here's the bug to star for path: support: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3732

Comment: @SethLadd thanks for the issue link, added to answer and also some of your edits.